# sending email and then passing data then opening activity using one intent

Tags: android, email, android-intent

so i want to send an email notifying that they registration is complete , and in that email there a confirmation code to be used in the next activity , and is there a way to open the a mail app after the email has been send to that email , then after sending that mail i wanna pass the code through intent so i can verify the entered code.... i tried out my self but it does not seem to work....

```
     try {  
        if (name.getText().toString().length()>0 
                        &
        email.getText().toString().length()>0 
                    &
       psswd.getText().toString().length()>0) 
                {
                    Random random = new Random();
                    int value = random.nextInt(10000);

                    Intent fdbckint = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    fdbckint.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, email.getText().toString());
                    fdbckint.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Bar Stock Control ");
                    fdbckint.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "THANK YOU FOR SIGNING UP MR/MRS:"+name.getText().toString()+"<b> HERE IS YOUR CODE "+value+
                            "ENTER THAT CODE TO FINIALIZE YOUR SIGN UP. AND INCASE YOU FORGET YOUR PASSWORD "+psswd.getText().toString());
                    fdbckint.setType("message/rfc822");

                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(fdbckint, "wordshare feedback option"));

                    Intent i =new Intent(getActivity(), singup_final.class);
                    i.putExtra("na", name.getText().toString());
                    i.putExtra("email", email.getText().toString());
                    i.putExtra("code", value);
                    i.putExtra("passwd", psswd.getText().toString());
                    startActivity(i);

                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "jesus man! really !! fill those box up  ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception

            }
```

Comment: change & to &&.. or you will do AND operation on length

Comment: As per my opinion  `startActivity(Intent.createChooser(fdbckint, "wordshare feedback option"));` in your `singup_final` Activity

Comment: i didn get that @SimplePlan

Comment: You did not start both Intent so my advice first you navigate to your singup_final Activity  and in that activity display email intent

Comment: it works now.... i use getactivity() instead of rootview... silly me !! thanks for the help by the way

Comment: my method has back fired... now the new activity has been opened and still the createchooser hasnt been called.. but when i hit back button  thats when the creatchooser comes up... !! @SimplePlan